# Generic query for both oracle and sql server databases?

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I am working on a functionality where i need to check whether database is down or not. i have  to use single query which works for both oracle and sqlserver dbs. is there any single query which checks whether db is up or not?

similar to `select * from dual;`

Thanks!

Comment: Create a table with named dual. it's workaround.

Comment: What happens if the database goes down immediately after you check it? Have you considered just running your queries and catching any exceptions that are thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` and not with a select.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to use the Connection's function to check the server is available.
There should be an Exception when it fails to connect and you can check the state to see if it's still open.

To address your specific need, if you decide to continue with a query.
**THIS IS NOT BEST PRACTICE**
I don't know of a simple way to do what you wish, Oracle and SQL don't share the same naming for system objects. BUT run that command, it won't work on SQL, but the exception won't be of type 'Server is Down' and you can use it in your try/catch.
**THIS IS NOT BEST PRACTICE**

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to obtain the connection and then use the database metadata information like the product version or product name to ensure the database is up or not.

Eg:

```
try{ 
  Con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL,username,password);
  databasemetadata = con.getMetaData();
  String databaseName = databasemetedata.getDatabaseProductName();
 If(databaseName.equals("<desireddabase>"))
  {
     //database up and running
  }
}
 catch(Exception e)
{
  // error in connection ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java.sql.Connection has a method

```
isValid(timeOut)
```

> Returns true if the connection has not been closed and is still valid. The driver shall submit a query on the connection or use some other mechanism that positively verifies the connection is still valid when this method is called.